# How to get number of links to javascript object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, graph-algorithm

I have this data:

```
const main = 'test1';
const data = [
  {
    from: 'test1',
    to: 'test2'
  },
  {
    from: 'test2',
    to: 'test3'
  },
  {
    from: 'test3',
    to: 'test4'
  },
  {
    from: 'test4',
    to: 'test2'
  },
  {
    from: 'test1',
    to: 'test4'
  }
];
```

I want to get the number of links to the main node (in this case *test1*). For example, if we look at node *test3*, it takes 2 links to get to *test1*:

*test3 → test2 → test1*

Same thing with node *test2*, it takes 1 link to get to *test1*.

What's the best way to calculate this? In the end, I want the **longest** number of links to *test1*. In the example case it's 3:

*test3 → test2 → test4 → test1*

Comment: iterate and calculate

Comment: Why is 3 the longest number? May every node only be visited once?

Comment: Are circular references possible?

Comment: You should try yourself something https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Post your code, that you are trying.

Comment: Just to give you a pointer since this answer is a bit more involved than you might expect. You are no longer talking about arrays here but rather about graphs. There has been done a lot of research about traversing graphs. A similar but inverted case is the shortest path in a graph which is known as [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Maybe this helps you find an answer?

Comment: I don't see any link fro  `test3->test2` as you stated. how can you reach `test1` from `test3` as per your given data set? Also I can see none of the node's destination is `test1`

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee `test3` is linked to `test1` via `test2`, look at it as a line, it doesn't have to explicitly have `from test3 to test2`, it works vice versa.

Comment: so, from dosen't meant source, and to dosen't meant destination? it's just a path?

Comment: @Case09 then why dont `test4->test3->test2->test1`? you have link within `test3` and `test4` as well right?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee Because `test4` is directly connected to `test1`, so longest path is still `test3->test2->test1`, because `test3` is only connected to `test1` via `test2`. Hope i understood your question.

Comment: so you need the only exist longest path, in case of multiple path (one short, one long) the longest path cannot be taken?

Comment: `from` and `to` seem very suggestive names for a *directed* link. Could you be explicit on whether the links are *directed* (can be traversed only from `from` to `to`), or whether they are *undirected*, meaning that the opposite traversal is also possible?

Comment: Just to add that if links are undirected, and there is a way to go through at least 2 links to the target, one can always traverse the first link back-and-forth 100 times before traversing the next link towards the target. So that really would take out the fun of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to visit each possible path. However if a cycle is encountered and the target node is reachable, then the longest distance becomes infinity, as one may go through that cycle any number of times.

To visit all paths, you can use a recursive function.

Here is one:

```js
function find(data, sourceName, targetName) {
    // Create hash data structure keying nodes by their name
    const map = new Map(data.map(({from}) => [from, []]));
    data.forEach(({from,to}) => map.get(from).push(map.get(to)));
    // If links are supposed to be undirected, allowing traversal in both directions
    //   then uncomment this:
    // data.forEach(({from,to}) => map.get(to).push(map.get(from)));
    const target = map.get(targetName);
    // Recursive function
    function recur(node) {
        if (node === target) return 0; // Found target
        if (node.visited) { // Cycle; mark node for detection during backtracking 
            node.onCycle = true;
            return -Infinity;
        }
        node.visited = true;
        let dist = 1 + Math.max(...node.map(recur)); // Maximise path length
        node.visited = false;
        // Leave out next line if longest path should not include cycles
        if (node.onCycle && dist > 0) return Infinity; // Solution path can have cycles
        return dist;
    }
    const dist = recur(map.get(sourceName)); // Start!
    return dist < 0 ? null : dist; // Return null when target cannot be reached
}

const data = [{from: 'test1', to: 'test2'},{from: 'test2', to: 'test3'},{from: 'test3',to: 'test4'},{from: 'test4',to: 'test2'},{from: 'test1',to:'test4'}];
const longestDist = find(data, 'test1', 'test3');
console.log(longestDist);
```

Note that this solution will not continue a search passing through the target node and then trying to find it from there again (through a cycle). In other words, it assumes a path may only contain the target as its last node, not multiple times.

In case you want to exclude paths that have cycles, then remove the line that returns `Infinity` as distance.

The code assumes the links to be *directed*. In case the links are to be understood as bi-directional (a.k.a *undirected*), meaning that if one direction is specified, the opposite direction is also possible without explicitly including it as a mirrored link, then uncomment the second `forEach` line in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be redefined in graph theory terms: "test1", "test2",... are vertices, the data array contains edges (pairs "from-to") - so we have graph - finding the longest path in graph is the NP-hard problem - [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). So you need to check all possible paths to find the longest